# SharePoint 2016 - missing server dependencies OOTB

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, health-analyzer, minrole

I have a freshly built 2016 Standard Server Farm using autospinstaller in a 4 server farm using MinRoles. The main web application and the my site web application are both reporting missing server side dependencies. This is a fresh build using out of the box default configuration. I manually created a test web application to rule out autospinstaller and it is now reporting the same. The missing features are 2016 features.  The September CU has been applied. 
This article says to ignore search errors but I have more than that. I did create a search center.
[TechNet Missing server side dependencies](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt718488(v=office.16).aspx)

The missing features are provided below.

```
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [643e64f2-f484-0c7d-cbda-044ed3c44a46] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.MySharedContext] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [70a3a34b-5605-b4b6-a17c-05d844c3c78d] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.FollowedCountsWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [79bd35e7-9add-ed7f-9098-08ce54fcf2a7] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SocialCommentWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [058f341f-7b40-b2d6-8cda-21028ff4c6a1] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.TaggedPeopleListWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [c01b6c09-055e-cb41-31be-24a416ce5049] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.TaggedUrlListWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [c7060141-4bde-d951-d38c-456e813ef16c] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileManages] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [7006b443-3b00-fe16-e42d-57927cc2be83] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileInfoWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [b2922567-b718-19c2-0c2b-5b45ba6f4fb6] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.BlogView] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [d6c8eb8f-cf28-daff-5b14-5edeab655f18] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.AnalyticsHashTagWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [6d04058e-47c5-c17e-d161-720d39d0d03c] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.PeopleWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [1c7111a3-2641-c283-6ced-92afa899c8bf] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.MySitePersonalSiteUpgradeOnNavigationWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [2] times in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [43a3910c-1a88-b4e4-03af-a6a49d1c6a48] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.PublishedFeedWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [2] times in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [7d38305c-72db-5f93-84c0-aa52134537df] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SiteDocuments] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [297bb5ba-8a6a-857a-b1ff-bef20d6fd130] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.MicroFeedWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [ffdc5ac7-c118-e42d-79b6-c16470839314] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.TagInformationWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [e85e13c0-9275-6d9e-eb9b-d99582fa6ad4] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.MySiteFirstRunExperienceWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [eab55457-f90a-9c12-d08c-e6bcf8e9cc08] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.AskMeAboutWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_MySites], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 

    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [0f676169-0639-1e85-ade6-0fd81be9f2aa] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.TableOfContentsWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [3fbacd03-20cb-fbb9-8306-1ef66af965ec] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.GettingStartedWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [2] times in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [1c9da91c-fe22-55e1-924e-43ea23206d94] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.RefinementScriptWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [9] times in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [11f30395-1fdc-7c77-5218-582960a07ed9] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.DocumentSetPropertiesWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [2] times in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [082ad9d5-0f8a-c2a2-22be-58f525052677] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.MediaWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [6] times in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [7fc3ecfc-46fd-e586-1c81-77eafa60353a] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchBoxScriptWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [12] times in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [ec0644c7-606c-feef-f929-7a0528fd6ddc] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ContactFieldControl] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [2] times in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [64ae8577-bd94-fa5b-8345-a5db33d8bc04] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.AdvancedSearchBox] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [3] times in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [7e83703a-8a5b-c861-17a0-b91376612391] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ResultScriptWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [9] times in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [f5c5cf4f-da4f-36be-2110-f321fd8b17fd] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchNavigationWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [7] times in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [03fe315a-53c4-db1b-5602-fde0af845534] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.DocumentSetContentsWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [8] times in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [SP_Content_Portal], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 

    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [d776845d-b1cd-923a-a779-01ecd8ef5bc6] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SiteFeedWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [2] times in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [3fbacd03-20cb-fbb9-8306-1ef66af965ec] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.GettingStartedWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [2] times in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [1c9da91c-fe22-55e1-924e-43ea23206d94] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.RefinementScriptWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [2] times in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [11f30395-1fdc-7c77-5218-582960a07ed9] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.DocumentSetPropertiesWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [082ad9d5-0f8a-c2a2-22be-58f525052677] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.MediaWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [7fc3ecfc-46fd-e586-1c81-77eafa60353a] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchBoxScriptWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [3] times in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [ec0644c7-606c-feef-f929-7a0528fd6ddc] (class [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ContactFieldControl] from assembly [Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [64ae8577-bd94-fa5b-8345-a5db33d8bc04] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.AdvancedSearchBox] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [7e83703a-8a5b-c861-17a0-b91376612391] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ResultScriptWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [2] times in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [f5c5cf4f-da4f-36be-2110-f321fd8b17fd] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchNavigationWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1] times in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts. 
    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [03fe315a-53c4-db1b-5602-fde0af845534] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.DocumentSetContentsWebPart] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [2] times in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_TEST_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been resolved. The comment about the content web applications is somewhat correct. The thing to remember is that this is **SharePoint 2016 using MinRoles**. With MinRoles one does not get the option in the services on server to turn on the web application role by server. With MinRoles, one specifies which server(s) will get the WFE role.

Since I used AutoSPInstaller and let it run on multiple machines, I think there was some overlap on the operations it was performing. My suggestion is to let AutoSPInstaller run on the first server until completed.

My corrective action was to delete both of my web applications (main and my sites). Once deleted, I went to the WFE server and reran AutoSPInstaller so it could re-provision the main web application and the my sites web application.
This allowed SharePoint MinRoles to manage the web application deployment without any conflicts of running AutoSPInstaller on multiple servers.

The end result was the web applications being deployed to the Application Server, the Distributed Cache Server and the WFE server. The Search Server did not get the web applications. Health Analyzer was no longer reporting the missing server side dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

this is something expected in multi server environment with different servers.

> All servers in a SharePoint farm run the SharePoint Timer Service.
>   This service makes all farm servers (no matter which role they have)
>   randomly pick timer jobs out of a pool of jobs that are due to be
>   executed. Health Analyzer jobs are triggered by those kind of timer
>   jobs.
>
> Unfortunately, the Health Analyzer rule responsible for checking
>   missing server side dependencies is only checking resources on the
>   particular machine the timer job is executed on. And this somehow is
>   by design. If one of your APP servers is in charge of running the
>   timer job, the result is going to be: local IIS ressources, that are
>   expected on the machine, are missing. The Health Analyzer rule found
>   those references within the content databases and tries to find them
>   on the machine. Unsuccesfully. If the same Health Analyzer rule is
>   executed by your WFE server, you’ll get a totally different result.

**Possible workarounds**

Carefully review, understand and discuss following possible workarounds:

1. Provision Central Administration and all content Web Applications on
   all farm servers
2. Duplicate virtual directories of Central Administration and all
   content Web Applications onto servers, that do not run Central Admin
   or content Web Applications
3. Ignore the Health Analyzer error
4. Disable the “Missing Server Side Dependencies” rule definition

read more about this over here: [Missing server side dependencies errors on your multi server SharePoint farm](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/christianheim/2016/09/15/missing-server-side-dependencies-errors-on-your-multi-server-sharepoint-farm/)